# Writing "WriteLine" message to trace window in Windows Workflow 4.5

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am using rehosted-designer of WF 4.5 to give an interface for the users to create a workflow with custom activities and some of the inbuilt activities of the framework.

I am using AsyncCodeActivity model (perfect fit for my requirement), and hence is bound to execute a workflow as below, i mean execution is triggered at once without the possibility to iterate the activities in the workflow:

```
WorkflowApplication wf = new WorkflowApplication(activeFlowChart);
............
............
var result = wf.BeginRun(null,null);
while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
Thread.Sleep(1);
continue;
}
wf.EndRun(result);
```

My workflow can have multiple "WriteLine" activities scattered in the workflow.
I want to retrieve the message of a particular "WriteLine" and show in the trace window as in the order how it appears in the workflow.

I have tried as below on completion, which displays all the "WriteLine" messages appended at the end of the execution:

```
wf.Extensions.Add(writer);
wf.Completed = arg =>
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(writer.ToString()))
{
//display
}
};
```

I am looking for a way to get the "WriteLine" message immediately when it occurs in the workflow, not on completion.

Answer (score 0):

The below link helped me to think about writing custom TextWriter to solve the above usecase:

[Redirecting Console.WriteLine() to Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726852/redirecting-console-writeline-to-textbox)

Instead of appending the characters to the "writer" object and print it to the display window when the workflow is completed (refer the code in my question), i wrote a custom TextWriter to print the message of each "WriteLine" activity when a new line("\r\n") is encountered. example below:

in constructor:

```
var writer = new WriteLineTextWriter(DisplayTraceMessage);
Console.SetOut(writer);
```

custom TextWriter:

```
public class WriteLineTextWriter : TextWriter
{
private Action<string, Brush> WriteTraceMessageToGUI { get; set; }
private StringBuilder line;
private byte counter;

public WriteLineTextWriter(Action<string, Brush> action)
{
WriteTraceMessageToGUI = action;
line = new StringBuilder();
}

public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
{
get { return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; }
}

public override void Write(char value)
{
if (value == '\r' || value == '\n')
{
counter++;
}
else
{
line.Append(value.ToString());
}
if (counter == 2)
{
WriteTraceMessageToGUI(line.ToString(), Brushes.BlueViolet);
line.Clear();
counter = 0;
}
}

public override void Write(string value)
{
WriteTraceMessageToGUI(value, Brushes.BlueViolet);
}
}
```